# Parallel SSH - no module named gevent error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, gevent, traceback

I installed parallel-ssh using pip (I don't why it installed for Python 2.7; does it not come for Python 3?), and then I tried to import in the IDLE to use. I was following the quick start guide on the online docs. It gave me an error saying there is "no module named gevent".

Here is the entire error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pssh.pssh_client import ParallelSSHClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pssh/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .pssh_client import ParallelSSHClient
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pssh/pssh_client.py", line 24, in <module>
    from gevent import monkey  # noqa: E402
ImportError: No module named gevent
```

From the docs, it says

> ParallelSSH uses gevent’s monkey patching to enable asynchronous use of the Python standard library’s network I/O.
>
> Make sure that ParallelSSH imports come before any other imports in
>   your code. Otherwise, patching may not be done before the standard
>   library is loaded which will then cause ParallelSSH to block.
>
> If you are seeing messages like This operation would block forever,
>   this is the cause.

This is the first thing I import, so I don't know why it is giving an error. Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

Comment: install gevent using pip, I also faced this problem when I was trying to install Paramiko

Comment: @AdriánKálazi I tried installing gevent, but it gave me an error saying "failed building wheel for gevent".

Answer (score 1):

Does not look like gevent installation was completed.

Try:

```
pip install -U pip
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U parallel-ssh
```

To be able to install binary wheels, used by both gevent and parallel-ssh, pip/setuptools need to be upgraded.

Building from source requires compiler and header files which you may not have.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the module for Python 2.7 then it wont work in your Python 3 interpretor. If Python 2.7 is your default interpretor, you should just need to call the pip command using the Python 3 command

You probably ran this command to install the module:

```
[root@server] python -m pip install <module>
>> Requirement already satisfied: <module> in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Try this command:

```
[root@server] python3 -m pip install <module>
>> Requirement already satisfied: <module> in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Comment: Is it a problem if my Python install is owned by the OS? It was taking a really long time to install and I cancelled the operation because I didn't want to proceed any further.